# When resizing textarea, all elements move down: How to fix

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, textarea

**Problem Statement**

Whenever I resize the textarea in my Angular website, all the elements move down, which is something I do not want.

---

**A Technical Caveat**

I want the user to be able to resize the textarea by themselves. It is something that must be a part of the functionality of the website.

---

**Code**

**HTML for the Textarea**

```
<mat-form-field class="XPContain" appearance="outline">
    <textarea matInput cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Describe your past experience"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS for the Textarea**

```
.XPContain {
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
}
```

---

**Images of the Problem**

When the textarea is *not* resized by the user:

[image]

When the textarea *is* resized by the user:

[image]

---

**Explanation of Images**

As you can see, whenever the user resizes the textarea, it moves all the other elements down.

---

**Expected Results**

I want the textarea to resize independently from all the other elements and not move any elements.

---

**Actual Results**

The textarea moves all the elements down whenever resized.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? It does not seem to be the default behavior for mat-form-field to act like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyyb45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was small. All I needed to do was change `position: relative` to `position: absolute`. It was a minor detail that I did not notice before posting my question.

Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

use : `position: relative`

checkout the doc here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lgj3n65s/

Comment: Please provide a working demo to understand the problem

Comment: Ah-ha, I actually found the problem. I am going to answer my own question. It was something small of course!

Answer (score 0):

Add **vertical-align: top** in **XPContain** class